# How do I write a string in a particular position in pdf?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to write a string in some random location in pdf page in java language.
Please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you need a third-party API Library of some sort to create/manipulate PDFs (Unless you roll your own, of course).

A quick Google search brings up http://itextpdf.com/ which may help you.